# Android Support Library and Media Router .jar files cannot be found

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.android, android-support-library

I am totally new to Xamarin. I want to add map to the default hello world in Xamarin.Android. I have prepared my Manifest step by step from the guide. Also downloaded the support library via sdk manager but I get errors asking me to install SL and SL media Router.

Here the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to receive remote notifications from Google Play Services -->
<!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.MyAppName.MyAppName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.MyAppName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application android:label="@string/app_name">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCV3Xs4ah1VkL8dI2JWmP2UiTlH4HZuQfQ" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

And some of the errors I get:

```
  /Users/apple/Projects/MyAppNameAndroid/MyAppNameAndroid: Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file /Users/apple/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/21.0.3/embedded/classes.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (MyAppNameAndroid)

/Users/apple/Projects/MyAppNameAndroid/MyAppNameAndroid: Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r10.zip and extract it to the /Users/apple/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/21.0.3/content directory. (XA5209) (MyAppNameAndroid)

/Users/apple/Projects/MyAppNameAndroid/MyAppNameAndroid: Error XA5209: Reason: /Users/apple/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/21.0.3/android_m2repository_r10.zip is not a valid zip file (XA5209) (MyAppNameAndroid)


/Users/apple/Projects/MyAppNameAndroid/MyAppNameAndroid: Error XA5206: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory /Users/apple/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/21.0.3/embedded/. doesn't exist. (XA5206) (MyAppNameAndroid)

/Users/apple/Projects/MyAppNameAndroid/MyAppNameAndroid: Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r10.zip and extract it to the /Users/apple/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter/21.0.3/content directory. (XA5209) (MyAppNameAndroid)
```

I also downloaded the mentioned .zip file in the url but
there is no such folder as `/users/apple/.local` ... to copy it in.

Is it really this tricky to add map permissions to an app or I'm doing sth wrong?

Comment: Look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437601/error-after-updating-the-android-support-library-v7-appcompat-to-the-21-0-3-vers?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_1_-_maps_application/). Xamarin has a guide in how to add and setup a map fragment.

You also need to install the google play services component from the Xamarin component store, not from the Android SDK manager.