# After rebuild the support package "23.1.1.0" folder is empty

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-support-library, xamarin-studio, telerik-appbuilder

```
Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory "**AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.1.1.0\embedded\./** "doesn't exist.  test
```

I added Android Support Library v7 AppCompat Package . after adding the package it giving this error. but the folder is empty. i rebuild many times but its creating empty folder. Please help me How can i resolve this problem.

Comment: I think I had the same problem ... I used nuget(Tools=>NuGet Package Manager=>Manage NuGet Packages for Solution) to uninstall this package and then I installed it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error after updating the Android.Support Library v7 AppCompat to the 21.0.3 version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437601/error-after-updating-the-android-support-library-v7-appcompat-to-the-21-0-3-vers)

Comment: I flagged this as a possible duplicate, different version of the nuget package, but same issue

Comment: I Tried so many times but no use.